# Asus Laptop Ubuntu 16.04 stuck at purple screen

Tags: 16.04, login

All of a sudden today my Asus Laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 will not boot. After choosing "Ubuntu" at the grub menu, I get stuck at a purple screen  (not displaying any logos, just purple color screen).

I tried going to recovery mode --> continue normal boot, which got further up to to the user login screen. However, this time it got stuck at the login screen i.e.  typing the password, and after a few seconds it again shows the login screen.

The most important thing to me is not to lose any of the files of the laptop! What would you suggest as a solution, without losing any files?

edit: With ctrl + alt + f2 I was able to login in to bash mode after recovery mode --> continue normal boot, but not sure what to do from there.

edit2: Checking the disk space with `df -h` on the main partition, it started at 80% used space and I witnessed it increasing fast to 100%, without me doing anything. I m not sure why the free disk space is decreasing on it's own, I suppose it is related to the problem

Comment: It was syslog and kern.log that were increasing rapdily. I added nopci and noaer options to grub file to stop log messages related to pci.

After rebooting 2-3 times and leaving it for a long time, I finally entered into the login screen, without  requiring recovery mode. I m not sure if my changes were actually related to the problem.

Comment: Yet the problem seems to persist. After rebooting, the laptop is stuck for at least 20-30 minutes on a purple loading screen, or indefinitely some times.